# Adding (& naming) or deleting a set of UI elements from a UI

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I'm making a UI in maya where I would like a dropdown tab with a set of `textFieldButtonGrp` to be either created (with a prompt to name the tab)or deleted when I press add '+'or remove'-' button.

Code for UI (with one tab):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMaya as om
import math

from functools import partial


###################################################################################
            #TOOL WINDOW#                       #TOOL WINDOW#
###################################################################################
def frameCollapseChanged(ToolWindow):
         cmds.evalDeferred("cmds.window('ToolUI', e=1, h=sum([eval('cmds.' + cmds.objectTypeUI(child) + '(\\'' + child + '\\', q=1, h=1)') for child in mc.columnLayout('" + ToolWindow + "', q=1, ca=1)]))")

     #check to see if window exists
if cmds.window("ToolUI", exists = True):
     cmds.deleteUI("ToolUI")
     #create window
ToolWindow = cmds.window("ToolUI", title = "Tool UI", mnb = True, mxb = False,)
    #create a main layout
mainLayout = cmds.columnLayout (adjustableColumn=True)

form = cmds.formLayout()
tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=5, innerMarginHeight=5,cr=True)
cmds.formLayout( form, edit=True, attachForm=((tabs, 'top', 0), (tabs, 'left', 0), (tabs, 'bottom', 0), (tabs, 'right', 0)) )
###################################################################################
            #SETUP TAB CONTENT#                       #SETUP TAB CONTENT#
###################################################################################
child1 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=1,adjustableColumn=True)
cmds.text(label = 'Root Joint Selection', align ='center')
cmds.button(label = 'Add Selector', command=lambda event:Name_DialogBox())

cmds.setParent( '..' )

###################################################################################
            #TOOL TAB CONTENT#                       #TOOL TAB CONTENT#
###################################################################################

child2 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, columnWidth=(300,250),adjustableColumn=True)

cmds.columnLayout(columnAttach=('both', 5),columnWidth=300, columnAlign="center", adjustableColumn=True )
cmds.text(label = 'FK IK Switch', align ='center')



cmds.setParent( '..' )
cmds.setParent( '..' )

###################################################################################
            #TOOL TABS#                                #TOOL TABS#
###################################################################################
cmds.tabLayout( tabs, edit=True, tabLabel=((child1, 'Set Up'), (child2, 'Tool')) )

cmds.showWindow()


winHeight = 0
     # iterate through all children of the main layout
for child in cmds.columnLayout(mainLayout, q=1, ca=1):
         # for each child, get it's type, then use that run an eval command to get that ui item's 
         #height and add it to the height variable
     winHeight += eval('cmds.' + cmds.objectTypeUI(child) + '("' + child + '", q=1, h=1)')
     # set the window height with the gathered height values
cmds.window('ToolUI', e=1, h=winHeight) 


#################################################################################################################
            #CREATE SELECTION LISTS#                                #CREATE SELECTION LISTS# 
#################################################################################################################

def Name_DialogBox():
    result = cmds.promptDialog(
            title='Rename Object',
            message='Enter Name:',
            button=['OK', 'Cancel'],
            defaultButton='OK',
            cancelButton='Cancel',
            dismissString='Cancel')

    if result == 'OK':
        InstanceName = cmds.promptDialog(query=True, text=True)
        print InstanceName
        ###Create New Tab using text as name####
        New_Tab_Set(InstanceName)
        return InstanceName




class New_Tab_Set:

    def __init__(self, InstanceName):
        self.name = InstanceName


    def Set_up_Tab(self):

        self.tab1=cmds.frameLayout (width = 300, label = self.name,  collapse = True, collapsable = True, marginWidth = 5, parent = child1);
        self.cmds.text(label = self.name, align ='center')
        self.tsL0 =cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(ed=False, adj=1,cal=(1,"left"),cw3=(10,100,25), cl3=("left","left","left") , 
                                    buttonLabel='Root   FK',bc = 'Create_Selection_Chains.select_joints_afk(left_arm_select)' )
        self.gtF0 = tsL0 

        self.tsL1 = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(ed=False, adj=1,cal=(1,"left"),cw3=(10,100,25), cl3=("left","left","left") , 
                                    buttonLabel='Wrist   IK',bc = 'Create_Selection_Chains.select_joints_aikw(left_arm_select)')
        self.gtF1 = tsL1

        self.tsL2 = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(ed=False, adj=1,cal=(1,"left"),cw3=(10,100,25), cl3=("left","left","left") , 
                                    buttonLabel='Elbow IK',bc = 'Create_Selection_Chains.select_joints_ikpv(left_arm_select)' )
        self.gtF2 = tsL2

        self.cmds.separator(h=5)
        self.cmds.button(label= 'Remove' + self.name, command = 'Remove()', width=100)
        self.cmds.separator(h=5)
```

My problem is that I'm unsure how to add the New_Tab content into the UI

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: im not sure where you are stuck. Do you ask how to add a button to a layout with your + button ?

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear. Im stuck with adding the + and - & adding or removing the dropdowns. I had both sections higlighted in red in the picture but it didnt save that way. Ill change it as soon as I can.

Comment: Let's be crystal clear: You want a `+` button to prompt the user to enter a name for a new `frameLayout` that will be created with multiple `textFieldButtonGrp` widgets? How does the `-` button work? I understand that it's suppose to remove a `frameLayout`, but how is it suppose to know *which* one to remove? Also, what have you tried so far? This code has made no attempt to make these buttons.

Comment: i agree with Green Cell. One advice that might help you, you might need to think as "widget". If you want to add or remove something in your layout, this layout thing should be created by a function. You store then the output of this function in a dictionnary so you can parse this and remove them later on (maybe with an id number to order them and remove them)

Comment: Personally I would dynamically create a tiny remove button for every widget. DrWeeny's idea with a dictionary and what index to remove is a good alternative too.

Comment: Thank you both! I edited my question since I was asking multiple questions that should probably be in a new question. I also added my attempt at achieving this. I hope this is more clear. I think I might want to stick with GreenCells Idea since I'm not familiar with dictionaries, so I added the remove to the dropdown tab